# There is a way to {% extends '' %} parent html from alternative folder in template?

Tags: django, extends

My project has several customers. Each app has html files that need to be specific for that customer, althogh has the same name.

My approach to solve this was a variable which holds the folder's name with customer's html files, before the template's path,
with this:

```
{% extends {{FOLDER_NAME}}'account/form/base.html' %}
```

instead this:

```
{% extends 'account/form/base.html' %}
```

of-course this don't work and I was wondering if there is a way to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `{% extends FOLDER_NAME|add:'account/form/base.html' %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are inside `{% %}` you should not use `{{}}`.

Instead just directly use the name inside `{% %}` and string concat it with the rest of your url using `|add:` syntax.

So in your case

```
{% extends FOLDER_NAME|add:'account/form/base.html' %}
```

will work.